# Very slow performance of pandas DataFrame division

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I`m currently working on some simple DataFrame and after measuring its performance I have encountered some weird behavior. Here are the problematic code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=list(range(6)), columns=['rand', 'result'])
df['rand'] = [0.15, 0.07, 0.74, 0.37, 0.54, 0.07]

time_start = time.time()
df['result'] = df['rand'] / 2 #Here lays the problem
time_end = time.time()
print ('Generating calulation took: %.7f sec' % (time_end - time_start))
```

Everything works well but the performance is worse than bad. It takes about 0.7 second to pefrorm this simple calulation. For single useage this could be bearable but its part of many-instance class constructor, so it is totally unacceptable. Any ideas to optimize this code?

Comment: This statement takes 138 µs to run on my old 2013 Mac. What exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Honestly, i have no idea. After running this code I get performance above 0.6 seconds. It is totally strange because in other place of this DataFrame I perform very similiar division and it is made in no-time.

Comment: What Python and Pandas versions?

Comment: Python 3.6.3 Anaconda custom(64-bit) and 0.22.0 pandas

Comment: I get about 0.002 seconds on repl.it, which is painfully slow already, but nowhere near the absurdly atrocious 0.7 second timing you report.

Comment: I couldn`t belive it either. After compiling it at repl.it I get somewhere similiar results (0.002s). I`m so confused by this.

Comment: 418 µs ± 76.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) in my Juypter

Comment: Can you just work with the `ndarray`: `df.rand.values/2`?

Comment: It works! Thanks @ALollz! But still, i can`t really tell what creates this strange behavior.

Comment: Tried again locally, with pandas 0.22.0 and Python 3.6.3. 0.0008314 seconds. No sign of whatever's happening on your end.